# The Long Dark: Can I return to Milton after I finish episode 1?

Tags: the-long-dark

I'm playing The Long Dark. I've been tasked with climbing the mountain to get to Perseverance Mills. My question is, can I return to Milton afterwards? I have a lot of stuff hoarded and I would hate to leave it all behind.

Comment: I'm now at the same point, about to leave Milton. Did you find out the answer? Can you go back to Milton?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found out - you CANNOT return to Milton! 
You can take whatever you can carry though, so take that distress pistol, those military rations and good quality tools.

Some people have complained of a bug where they lose all their gear when starting Episode 2. Here's exactly what I did to avoid it:

1. Descend the mountain by the rocks next to the picnic area. The Episode doesn't end as soon as you've done this - so you still have a little time.

After

> the rope snaps

You can rest and eat. Then climb the other rope to continue.

2. Then follow the path round the mountain until you come to a cave. Enter the cave and follow the fairly linear path. When you come to the end a cutscene will play. **DON'T PRESS ANYTHING!** Let the cutscene play out, and also let the credits roll. They're not that long.

   3. Once credits have finished, you can continue. Click 'Wintermute' and then 'Resume'. An opening credits sequence will play. **DO NOT SKIP!** I couldn't remember if I'd seen it before, so I let it play out. Then sure enough, episode 2 started and I still had all my gear.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!! :D I was waiting to advance, hoping you'd share what you learned. Thanks again!